# Query Optimization - Performance Degradation with time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I've got a process that inserts about 1 million records a day into a table and it's been doing that for a year. I then have a secondary table that joins to the results table and selects a count of the results grouped by an id and status for the part three months. Everything has been going on fine but the query now is performing extremely slow , I can't seem to figure out what's gone wrong. Could someone point me towards where I'd need to start with to get the performance up.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?\

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You have constantly growing index or several and now they don't fit into memory. Running queries that use the indexes becomes slow, because parts of indexes are constantly loaded from swap, hence, using disk IO.

Comment: You should partition your table by date, this way when you filter by the last 3 months you will be able to handle just those datafiles involved, instead of using the whole table.

Comment: @newtover Does that mean I have to update the index ?

Comment: Too broad. To you maintain your DB? What does data model look like and indexes? How do slow queries look like, what are problematic actual execution plans? and so on.

Comment: Can you provide an estimated query plan?

Comment: Editing your question to add table schema(s), sample data, the query, and the execution plan will go a long way toward getting you some help.

Answer (score 1):

We can think of a table as of a large file on disk. To search some information in the file you need to scan it. This is expensive.

To make the process more efficient, RDBMS builds indexes - data structures, that are usually kept in memory, organised to simplify specific queries and for each row contain references where to find the row within the file. The more rows you have, the larger become indexes.

At some point the indexes become too large to fit into memory and parts of it are swapped into disk. Random access to popular indexes start causing a lot of disk IO operations, because the OS is constantly saving/loading parts of the indexes, and this is much slower than working with just memory.

What to do heavily depends on the data, there are several approaches, but the common idea behind them is to make popular indexes fit into memory again:

- you can just add some memory
- you can use smaller datatypes
- you can delete or merge indexes and rewrite queries to use the indexes in a certain way
- you can partition your data and distribute an index among several machines
- ...

And make sure you do use indexes, because if a table is rapidly growing, table scans of the whole table will slow down your queries very soon.